# Unable to deploy servlet using ojdbc in Webserver 7 from Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets, jdbc, war

Newbie warning: I am using Eclipse EE to develop my first "Hello World"-level servlets, for execution under Oracle's WebServer 7.  I can successfully develop a very simple servlet that uses just the onGet() method to dump out some simple HTML, and I can run it locally via Eclipse under Tomcat.  I can export a WAR file for that app, and then use WebServer's admin console to add it as a "web app".

BUT...
My second app, which is a proof of concept, adds JDBC into the mix.  I again put all logic in the doGet() method, and I do a simple read of an Oracle table.
This too runs run under Tomcat via Eclipse, but when I attemp to add the exported WAR file to webserver 7, the admin console hangs as soon as I press OK to upload the WAR.

- I have oracle's ojdbc6.jar on my build path as an external jar.
- Target java is 1.6, and Oracle is 11g.
- development machine has Java 1.7 as default JRE (1.6 is installed but I don't know how to / if I should connect to to this servlet).
- I let eclipse generate the web.xml file and have not altered it.

I jave built batch apps that use ojdbc6 many times.

So, I can deploy a simple servlet with no extra jar into webserver 7 OK.
I can run a servlet under tomcat that hits my remote database and reads data.
But I can't seem to take a WAR of that project and get it to upload into webserver 7 without hanging the admin console.

Do you have suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Once of my coworkers solved the problem for me.  There were two issues causing the problem:

1. Rather than using iPlanet to upload the WAR file (which hung immediately), he FTP'd the file to the server and installed the WAR file from the server itself.

   2. The target JRE I had specified was higher than the version installed on the server.  Setting my target JRE lower helped.